# How to find and update the nested object in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb

[image]

How to find and update the nested object in MongoDB?
I am trying but not working. Listen this in one document only of specific category. Fist I need to find a particular category then update the product stock.

```
 await db.collection("protablekeyboards").findOneAndUpdate({ 'category': "portable_keyboards", "products.sku": sku}).project({ products: 1 }).toArray()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$[identifier]](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#position-nested-arrays-filtered) and `arrayFilters`.

For Example :

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 1
},
{
  $set: {
    "products.$[elem].product_stock": 10
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "elem.sku": "sku_1"
    }
  ]
})
```

Here with the first, I match only the documents where `"_id": 1`

With the update query, I change the value of the `product_stock` variable in `products` to 10. But it only change the items of the array that match the `arrayFilters` condition.
Witch is where the `sku`is equal to `"sku_1"`

try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B22R2kluyVE)